# Test if an assertion is thrown

Tags: junit, junit4

How do I test if an assertion is thrown by the method under test using junit? Heres the method I'm testing:

```
public int f(int i){
    assert i > 0;
    return i;
}
```

I'm using junit 4.12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test it by providing parameter in `@Test` annotation:

```
@Test(expected = AssertionError.class)
public void shouldThrowExceptionWhenIncorrectInput() {
    f(-3);
}
```

This will check if the `AssertException` is thrown. 
However, if you want to ensure that this function wont be run with incorrect parameters, you have to be aware that assertions can be turned off by running java with `-da` parameters.

To ensure that exception is thrown I would suggest throwing `IllegalArgumentException` inside some validation method, and to provide it with proper message. Then you will be sure that this will always throw exception when incorrect parameters are provided.